# Can we connect to multiple group Id in kafkajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, kafka-consumer-api, kafkajs

We have our kafka consumer application where we have one consumer group and it gets connected to multiple topics using kafkajs node js library

```
const consumeMessages = async() = > {
  const consumer =
      kafka.consumer({groupId : 'test-group'})
          await consumer.connect() await consumer
              .subscribe({topic : 'test-topic', fromBeginning : true})
                  await consumer.run({
                    eachMessage : async({topic, partition, message}) =
                        > {console.log({
                            value : message.value.toString(),
                          })},
                  })
}
```

We want to change this approach where we want to have one consumer group for one topic . like if we have 5 topics we will have 5 consumer groups . In this case how to connect to multiple group Ids?

If I do it like this:

```
const consumer =
    kafka.consumer({groupId : 'test-group'}, {groupId : 'test-group1'},
                   {groupId : 'test-group2'})
```

It's not connecting and throwing errors , cannot connect to the broker.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: can you clarify if by `consumer group` you mean one consumer? And if you want separate instance of consumer then just create the consumers separately, why would you want to put different group ids in one consumer?

Comment: correct.. i want to create a 5 different consumers with different group ids..Is there any best way to create it

Comment: then you just have to follow the docs for creating consumers.